# Adding tags to an Ogg vorbis file that has NO tags using mutagen

Tags: python, mutagen

I have an ogg vorbis file with no tags.

How do I add tags to it? I cannot understand how to add tags from the mutagen documentation.

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mutagen/_file.py", line 41, in __init__
self.load(filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mutagen/ogg.py", line 464, in load
reraise(self._Error, e, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mutagen/ogg.py", line 460, in load
self.info = self._Info(fileobj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mutagen/oggvorbis.py", line 47, in __init__
page = OggPage(fileobj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mutagen/ogg.py", line 90, in __init__
    oggs, b"OggS", fileobj.tell() - 27))
mutagen.oggvorbis.OggVorbisHeaderError: read '\x1aE\xdf\xa3', expected 'OggS', at 0x0
```

Comment: First, the file you're reading isn't an Ogg-encoded media file...

Comment: The library producing it says it is...
>>> s = OggFileType()
>>> s.load('song.ogg')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mutagen/ogg.py", line 460, in load
        self.info = self._Info(fileobj)
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable